# La carte vitale, what does it mean?

Tags: terminologie

I came to the following: "la carte vitale"

What does this type refer to?

Comment: Please **READ** comments. **Stop** adding the **France** tag, **now**.

Comment: What isn't clear from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carte_Vitale)?

Answer (score 2):

La carte vitale est délivrée en France par la Sécurité Sociale, organisme national qui depuis 1945 rembourse une partie des frais médicaux des travailleurs.

Elle est nominative et concerne un assuré et sa famille. Elle a le format d'une carte bancaire.

Elle permet de ne régler que les frais non remboursés lorsque l'on règle le médecin, l'hôpital, le laboratoire, le pharmacien ou tout autre thérapeute qui se fait rembourser ensuite la part prise en charge par l'Assurance Maladie (nom officiel des centres de Sécurité Sociale).

Les mutuelles peuvent y être inscrites, le patient ne paie alors ni le complément de la consultation conventionnée ni la part non remboursée des médicaments ou autres frais pris en charge par leur mutuelle ; l'Assurance maladie leur envoie directement le relevé des prestations avec la part qu'elle a déjà réglée.

Comment: Je dois noter que cette carte d'assurance maladie est disponible dans plusieurs autre pays (comme au Canada, la carte soleil). Elle a la même fonction que la "carte vitale".